# How do I get a set of lat/lon points into OSMAND?

Tags: openstreetmap, android, latitude-longitude

I have a lat/lon points that I want to get into OSMAnd. What format do I need to put this in?

Comment: gpx https://code.google.com/p/osmand/wiki/HowToViewGPXTracks

Comment: alternatively you can add them to osmand's `favorites.gpx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load in your own data use the gpx file support:

Go to Map screen.

Tap device menu button.

Tap "Map Layers"
Check "GPX track".

A list of tracks will appear, named with the track starting date and time.  Check the desired track to view.

Tap OK. You will return to the map screen and zoom to the start of the track.

source:
https://code.google.com/p/osmand/wiki/HowToViewGPXTracks